# how to replace each all div element in one tr row with input and with the same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace each div element inside all td present inside a tr element.

Using jquery `.replaceWith()` method or any other method

to convert them all to inputs

I tried to do that like the following but it's not working

```
$('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ') td div').each()
.replaceWith("<input type='text' value=" + $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ') td div').val() + " />");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what it's doing instead of working. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: `.each()` - That is not how you use each. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: grammer correction spelling mistakes corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $this=$(this).find('td > div');
  $this.each(function(){
     var gettext= $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+gettext+'"/>');
  });
});
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: your answer inspired me to get the solution 
                $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ') td div').each(function () {
                    var gettext = $(this).text();
                    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + gettext + '"/>');
                });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
var getdivtext = $(this).find('td > div').text();
$(this).find('td > div').html('<input type="text" value="'+getdivtext +'"/>');
});
```

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I used `.clone()` to copy the `td`s. Then, by using `.each()`, I iterate through the **cloned** `td`s, do the replacement:

```
var copiedRow = $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ') > td').clone();
copiedRow.find('div').each(function(){
    $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ') > td').html("<input type='text' value=" + $(this).text() + " />");
})
```